# Magento 1.8.1.0 - Class 'Mage_Tag_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, helper

This error comes up when logging into admin dashboard:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Tag_Helper_Data' not found in /home/kartina/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Line #547:

```
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
```

I have tried to google up the problem, but can't find the solution.

Config files are as follows..

the whole "Retrieve helper object" in public_html/app:

```
/**
 * Retrieve helper object
 *
 * @param string $name the helper name
 * @return Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
 */
public static function helper($name)
{
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

---

in ..**/public_html/app/code/local/Pagayo/Main/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php

class Pagayo_Main_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

---

in ..**/public_html/app/code/local/Pagayo/Main/etc/config.xml:**

```
<modules>
    <Pagayo_Main>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Pagayo_Main>
</modules>

 <global>
    <helpers>
        <main>
            <class>Pagayo_Main_Helper</class>
        </main>
    </helpers>
 </global>

<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <pagayoall module="PAGAYO_MAIN">
                <file>pagayo_main.xml</file>
            </pagayoall>
        </updates>
    </layout>
     <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <pagayostore>
                                        <title>Pagayo Extensions Store</title>
                                    </pagayostore>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
               </children>
           </admin>
       </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
```

---

in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/adminhtml.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Magento
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
* needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
*
* @category    Mage
* @package     Mage_Catalog
* @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
* @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
*/
-->
<config>
    <menu>
        <catalog translate="title" module="catalog">
            <title>Catalog</title>
            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
            <!--action>adminhtml/catalog</action-->
            <depends>
                <module>Mage_Catalog</module>
            </depends>
            <children>
                <products translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <title>Manage Products</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/catalog_product/</action>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                </products>
                <categories translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <title>Manage Categories</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/catalog_category/</action>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                </categories>
                <attributes translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <title>Attributes</title>
                    <children>
                        <attributes translate="title" module="catalog">
                            <title>Manage Attributes</title>
                            <action>adminhtml/catalog_product_attribute/</action>
                        </attributes>
                        <sets translate="title" module="catalog">
                            <title>Manage Attribute Sets</title>
                            <action>adminhtml/catalog_product_set/</action>
                        </sets>
                    </children>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                </attributes>
                <urlrewrite translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <title>URL Rewrite Management</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/urlrewrite/index</action>
                    <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                </urlrewrite>
            </children>
        </catalog>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <catalog translate="title" module="catalog">
                                        <title>Catalog Section</title>
                                    </catalog>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                    <catalog translate="title" module="catalog">
                        <title>Catalog</title>
                        <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <attributes translate="title">
                                <title>Attributes</title>
                                <children>
                                    <attributes translate="title">
                                        <title>Manage Attributes</title>
                                    </attributes>
                                    <sets translate="title">
                                        <title>Manage Attribute Sets</title>
                                    </sets>
                                </children>
                            </attributes>
                            <categories translate="title">
                                <title>Manage Categories</title>
                            </categories>
                            <products translate="title">
                                <title>Manage Products</title>
                            </products>
                            <update_attributes translate="title">
                                <title>Update Attributes</title>
                            </update_attributes>
                            <urlrewrite translate="title">
                                <title>URL Rewrite Management</title>
                            </urlrewrite>
                        </children>
                    </catalog>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

---

thank you for your advice,
H

```
site: kartina.fm
```

////

---

### update

../app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Helper/Data.php was not visible (no thumbs and can't be editted/dowloaded/deleted - no data available at all).

Renamed the old Helper dir, created a new Helper dir, and uploaded a Data.php file from a 1yr old backup (that I was lucky to find.. yeah, I know):

```
<?php
/**
* Magento
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
* needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
*
* @category   Mage
* @package    Mage_Tag
* @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
* @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
*/

/**
* Tag data helper
*/
class Mage_Tag_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getStatusesArray()
    {
        return array(
            Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::STATUS_DISABLED => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Disabled'),
            Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::STATUS_PENDING  => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Pending'),
            Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::STATUS_APPROVED => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Approved')
        );
    }

    public function getStatusesOptionsArray()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Disabled'),
                'value' => Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::STATUS_DISABLED
            ),
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Pending'),
                'value' => Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::STATUS_PENDING
            ),
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Approved'),
                'value' => Mage_Tag_Model_Tag::STATUS_APPROVED
            )
        );
    }
}
```

---

the original error file has disappeared, now there is a new one error saying:

> There has been an error processing your request

The error log reccord says:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:62:"Indexer model should extend Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract.";i:1;s:3545:"#0 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(315): Mage::throwException('Indexer model s...')
#1 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php(41): Mage_Index_Model_Process->getIndexer()
#2 /home/kartina/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/index/notifications.phtml(27): Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->getProcessesForReindex()
#3 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/kartina/p...')
#4 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#5 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#6 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php(67): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#8 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Index_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications->_toHtml()
#9 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#10 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#11 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('notifications', true)
#13 /home/kartina/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('notifications')
#14 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/kartina/p...')
#15 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#16 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#17 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#21 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(43): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#22 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#23 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#24 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /home/kartina/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /home/kartina/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /home/kartina/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}";s:3:"url";s:70:"/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/8715fca154c2a31399457d30f8ca02a3/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: In separate php file try instantiating Mage::helper('tag'); and see the class by using get_class(). The error might be  because, in your system.xml you have used translate with no helper class.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but don't understand what exactly should I do step by step.. could you please share a link that explains this process? thank you.

Comment: is there any adminhtml.xml file is there ? if yes include in your question

Comment: does dashboard work when you disable Pagayo_Main module?

Answer (score 1):

It will be too lenghty to post this in comment so posting here.
In your magento directory make a file `test.php`

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app ();

$helper = Mage::helper ( 'tag' );
echo get_class ( $helper );

?>
```

run the file and check the class.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, created the php file and it gives out the same error:

    http://kartina.fm/test.php

error:
    Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Tag_Helper_Data' not found in /home/kartina/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: now go to directory app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Helper and see if Data.php is there

Comment: if it is not there, you have to create it. If it there then make a diff with fresh magento and check, if you have changed something.

Comment: thank you @Shrikant - I did update the main text //> new error

Comment: tell the path of helper file

Comment: path to helper: /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Helper/Data.php \\\ and the other one: /public_html/app/code/local/Pagayo/Main/Helper/Data.php (not sure of which one you ar talking about). thank you

Comment: re-run the test.php and see if you get class name

Answer (score 0):

No one can tell you why this error is there but you can **check this check list** to make sure those are things were there

1) login admin panel goto `system->configuration->Advanced->Advanced` and make sure `Mage_Tag` should be enable

2) goto `app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml` and make sure

```
 <Mage_Tag>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>core</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Catalog/>
        </depends>
    </Mage_Tag>
```

this node should be true.

3) check for compilation, if compilation is enable then disable compile and check. and it works then do recompile. for compilation go to `system->tool->compilation`

Comment: thank you Murtuza >> skipped the 1st suggestion as can't log into the admin panel // then went directly to #2 and here is a possible problem: there isn't a Mage_Tag.xml under /app/etc/modules/ .. will try to recreate one. thank you

Comment: @Helmuts My bad please check my updated answer